# RegEx Pattern + color word extracted

Tags: java, android, regex, string, colors

determine if a string has ^ and number 
Example : ^I love Android2 
And i want to get the word in a variable only if the string has ^ and a number at the end and i'd like to get the word without ^ and number , (its possible to have  : "^I love2 ^Android3 so much")<-- "I love" = colored ,"Android" = colored and "so much " = normal text.  then if the mumber is between 0-9 i have to make assign a color to this number . finaly i want to show the string in TextView with color and i think i have to use HTML format ;)

My regex is :

```
 Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^(.*):(\\d+)$");
```

if you have an idea tout assign color please tel me :)
But doesnt work :s
can someone help me ? :) and sorry for m'y bad english

Answer (score 0):

`^` as a special meaning in regex (start of string) so you have to escape it: `\\^`

Comment: Thanks i did this : ("^(\\^.*):(\\d+)$"); do you know how to return the result in a TextView ? @M42

Comment: @user2721721: No, sorry I don't know very much java.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex :

```
  (?<=\\^)([^0-9]+)
```

And the normal text can be extracted using :

```
  ([^^0-9]+$)
```

The color assigning can be done with something like this :

```
    Matcher mat = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\^)([^0-9]+[0-9]+)|([^^0-9]+$)")
                                   .matcher("^I love2 ^Android322 so much");

    while(matcher.find()){
        String match = matcher.group();
        String n= match.replaceFirst("^[^0-9]+", "");
        if(n.length()==1) {
            System.out.println(match.replaceFirst("[0-9]+$", "")+"=color_"+n);
        } else {
            System.out.println(match.replaceFirst("[0-9]+$", "")+"=normalText");
        }
    }
```

For the actual color assignment, however, n(single digit) won't represent the constants defined by [android.graphics.Color](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#BLACK). Say 1 mean RED and 9 mean BLUE in the supplied string, then add to the *if(true)* block the following :

```
 int color = Integer.parseInt(n) 
 switch(color){
     case 1 : color = 0xffff0000; break;
     case 9 : color = 0xff0000ff; break;
 }
 textview.setColor(color);
```

I've no idea on how to assign color to a part of text. I hope, you can find out.

Comment: Ok thanks i'd like to try but i dont know how to display the text without using "system.out.println " ? With a TextView is it possible ? @blackSmith

Comment: Great i tested and it work but could you explain the Integer.parse(n) ? @BlackSmith

Comment: I meant that you can use the integer value for some method of type text.setColor(int).  If you point out the class you are using to display the text, I may update the answer